# Command not redefined

Tags: macros

I am writing a custom package and would like to set the fraktur Real and Imaginary symbols to the standard `\mathrm{Re}` and `\mathrm{Im}`. I am trying to redefine them the standard and recommended way

```
\let\Re\relax \DeclareMathOperator*{\Re}{\mathrm{Re}}
\let\Im\relax \DeclareMathOperator*{\Im}{\mathrm{Im}}
```

The problem is that I am still getting the fraktur characters. When designing/using custom packages is there any reason why the above code would not be executed? For example, could another package be resetting what I am trying to do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\let\Re\relax \DeclareMathOperator\Re{\mathrm{Re}}
\let\Im\relax \DeclareMathOperator\Im{\mathrm{Im}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \Im [x + \i] + \Re[y + \i]
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: many packages (unicode-math for example) delay definitions until begin{document} try putting them after `\begin{document}`

Comment: Note that it should be `\DeclareMathOperator` *without* the asterisk.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: putting them after `\begin{document}` gives me `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble`

Comment: @egreg: thank you. Still no go on the redefined commands Im afraid.

Comment: oh of course (it _always_ helps if you provide a test file:-) Try putting them inside `\AtBeginDocument{...}` as the _last_ thing in the preamble

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Added a MWE. I tried commenting out the unicode-math package and it works fine without that package.   Unless `\AtBeginDocument{...}` is the _last_ thing this package won't work as I would like. How can I get this to work with having to make that the last command in the preamble.

Comment: It doesn't have to be last, just after unicode-math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I guessed before you posted the MWE this is due to `unicode-math` delaying its definitions.
You just need to delay yours as well. I aslo used `i` not `\i` as `\i` is invalid in math mode (and would be an unusual notation, `\imath` is the math version should you really need that)

```
\documentclass[10pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\Re\relax \DeclareMathOperator\Re{\mathrm{Re}}%
\let\Im\relax \DeclareMathOperator\Im{\mathrm{Im}}%
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation*}
    \Im [x + i] + \Re[y + i]
  \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does work, however, I am creating a package that ideally would be portable and include these macros upon using the package. Is this not possible? Also the `\i` I used is a style of `i` I prefer that is defined in the package. I forgot to take it out for the MWE.

Comment: Just saw your comment about it being _after_ unicode-math. Thank you.

Comment: Don't redefine the standard `\i` command!!!  as for order, since unicode-math defines these you have to redefine them after that, if you are loading unicode-math that is easy, if you are not then it's a bit harder

Comment: By the way, when would I know it is appropriate to do this? The log does not have any warning I can see.

Comment: warning about what i? I got `LaTeX Warning: Command \i invalid in math mode on input line 10.`

Comment: I will change the `\i` i have defined to something else.

Comment: thanks (otherwise you break turkish in which dotless i is a letter, plus any language that uses an accented i with the classic computer modern fonts where `\"{i}` is transformed to `\"\i` so you don't get three dots)

Comment: I meant some kind of indication that the command should be wrapped in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Comment: Oh that, no you are just supposed to know these things:-) (well if you define it and it is set back by the time the document starts then I would debug (if I hadn't guessed the answer) by adding `\show\Im` after every statement in the preamble to see where it got set back. In this case you would find that it was still your definition before `\begin{docuemnt}` but reset after it. that should be enough to suggest useing AtBeginDocument to get between those positions